# Copy style from one widget to another in python3 gtk3

Tags: python-3.x, fonts, widget, gtk3

I have a *GtkFontButton* with which user can select font. Button is set to change its font style (name, weight and size) after selection and also shows the new font and size. I want to copy this "font style" to only one label. Is it possible to do this without complex code? I can get from GtkFontButton the new font and size, using `widget.get_font_name()` (which returns a string, like "Sans Bold Italic 11").

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

class LabelWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Label Example")

        hbox = Gtk.Box(spacing=10)
        hbox.set_homogeneous(False)

        label = Gtk.Label("This is a normal label")
        hbox.pack_start(label, True, True, 0)

        self.labeltochange = Gtk.Label()
        self.labeltochange.set_text("This is a special label left-justified label.\nWith multiple lines.")
        hbox.pack_start(self.labeltochange, True, True, 0)

        label = Gtk.Label(
            "This is another label.\nWith multiple lines.")
        hbox.pack_start(label, True, True, 0)

        fb = Gtk.FontButton()
        fb.connect("font-set",self.test)
        hbox.pack_start(fb, True, True, 0)

        self.add(hbox)

    def test(self, widget):
        print(widget.get_font_name())

window = LabelWindow()
window.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
window.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

This prints on terminal the selected font and size. I want to do something like *self.labeltochange.set_style(widget.get_font_name())*
in order to change the font and size of the *self.labeltochange* to match the font and size every time the user selects a new font by clicking on the button. I thought that since *get_font_name()* returns a font and size *set_font_name* (to the returned string) could do the trick, but this was not a right thought though.

Comment: Share a MCVE please.

Comment: I am not sure what the V (in MCVE) means. My question is how to to copy "font style" from any GtkFontButton to one of the many labels in _any_ gtk window, so that only this one label will have the font that the GtkFontButton has, after user selection. Is not about some code with _Verifiable_ bug.

Comment: The V doesn't really apply in this case, does it? Anyway, I wanted to see some of your code, so I know exactly what you tried already.

Comment: Nothing of my tries is shown there.This is not the actual code (I load almost everything from glade file). I just was "forced" to write a sample. I tried all kind of `print(dir(someobject))` to find anything that will accept the string returned by `widget.get_font_name()` without success.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of Google came up with this method of using CSS (which is the recommended way of things in Gtk3):

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk

class LabelWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Label Example", name = 'Window')

        self.style_provider = Gtk.CssProvider()

        css = """
        #Label{
            background-color: red;
            border-radius: 10px;
            outline:none;
            font: Sans Bold 12;
        }
        """
        self.style_provider.load_from_data(bytes(css.encode()))
        Gtk.StyleContext.add_provider_for_screen(
            Gdk.Screen.get_default(), self.style_provider,
            Gtk.STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION
        )

        hbox = Gtk.Box(spacing=10)
        hbox.set_homogeneous(False)

        label = Gtk.Label("This is a normal label")
        hbox.pack_start(label, True, True, 0)

        self.labeltochange = Gtk.Label(name = 'Label')
        self.labeltochange.set_text("This is a special label left-justified label.\nWith multiple lines.")
        hbox.pack_start(self.labeltochange, True, True, 0)

        label = Gtk.Label(
            "This is another label.\nWith multiple lines.")
        hbox.pack_start(label, True, True, 0)

        fb = Gtk.FontButton()
        fb.connect("font-set",self.test)
        hbox.pack_start(fb, True, True, 0)

        self.add(hbox)

    def test(self, widget):
        font = widget.get_font_name()
        css = """
        #Label{
            font: %s;
        }
        """ % font
        self.style_provider.load_from_data(bytes(css.encode()))



window = LabelWindow()
window.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
window.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Comment: I am trying to avoid a really big bunch of code. `self.style_provider` loads css for all labels, not only for the one I choose temporarily to change. So in order to use this way, I have to write much more, error prune, code.

Comment: Pango markup is not so useful since the text contains malformed html code.  So I (temporarily) use the `GObject.markup_escape_text` to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

Stupid but almost working (*stupid* because adds tones of styles in label's style provider, *almost* because it may have side effects such as adding styles to children objects):

```
def on_buttonforselectfont_clicked(self, widget, *args):  
    font = widget.get_font_name()
    self.set_object_general_style(self.thelabelforsampleobject, 'font',font)

def set_object_general_style(self, theobject, var, val):
    css = '''*{''' + var + ''':''' + val + ''';}'''
    style_provider = Gtk.CssProvider()
    style_provider.load_from_data(css.encode('utf-8'))
    context = theobject.get_style_context()
    context.add_provider(style_provider,Gtk.STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION)
```